# Controller to execute AJAX requests for a client

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, controller, callback

I have been developing this structure or pattern (I don't really know how to call it). It's my first time doing something like this, and I'm a bit worried about the future, if it becomes unmanageable.

I'm looking for some advice on what could improve or remove to prevent that the one that has to work with this does not end trying to kill me.

This pattern is made to prevent repeated code and centralize all requests of a functionality.

It consists of two parts, the first one is the 'Controller' and the other one its the 'Client'.

The first part is the 'controller' where there are all the available ajax requests and the functions used in the scope. Going into more detail, the Controller receives a request object that contains the parameters to identify which request will be executed and the callbacks for that request.

And the client is where you can define the events, requests, callblacks, and the template specific functions, like a normal JS file.

This is the 'Controller':

```
    var FOF = FOF || {};//Namespace definition
    FOF.Users = {//Init User inside the namespace
    init: function(userRequest){//Main Function
    var request = userRequest.request || ''; //Request name as string
    var callbacks = userRequest.callbacks || {}; //Callbacks functions to run as ajax callbacks
    var userId = userRequest.userId || 0; //User Id param
    var event = userRequest.domainEvent || false; //Custom Event to be fired after the ajax request
    var dependency = userRequest.dependency ||  false; //Dependency injection
    var allowCache = userRequest.allowCache || false; //To allow load and store data from cache
    console.log(userRequest);
    if(allowCache){ //Cache variables
        var requestCache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(request));
        var currentDate = ((new Date).getTime());
        var cacheTimeHours = 1; //Cache Time in Hours
        var timeToUpdate = hoursToSeconds(cacheTimeHours);
    }



    switch(request) { //Request Switch
        case 'getUser':{//Get an user from a ajax request
            if(allowCache && requestCache != null && ((currentDate - requestCache.cacheLastUpdateDate)/1000) < timeToUpdate ){
                    console.log('From Cache');
                    callbacks.run(requestCache)

            }else{
                console.log('From ApiCall')
                FOF.Users.getUserData(callbacks,dependency,allowCache);
            }

            break;
        }
        default:{//Request Parameter empty or invalid
            console.log('Param Request Empty or not valid');
        }
    }


    },
    getUserData : function(callbacks,dependency,cache){ User data function

        dependency.ajax({
            url: "Mocks/users.json",
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'get',
            success: function (data) {

                if (!isObjectEmpty(callbacks)) { //Callbacks exec
                    callbacks.run(data);
                }
                if(event){//Event dispatch
                    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(event, {detail: {data}}));
                }
                if(cache){//Cache storage
                    storeInCache(data,'getUser'); //Es importante que se amacene el nombre de la cache con el mismo nombre de la request
                }

            },
            error : function (data) {
                if (!isObjectEmpty(callbacks)) {//Errors callbacks
                    callbacks.errors(data);
                }
                if(event){//Event dispatch
                    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(event, {detail: {data}}));
                }
            },
            cache: false,
        });


    }

}






/**
 * @description: Check if an object is empty by the ammount of keys
 */
function isObjectEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}



/**
 * @description: transform hours to seconds
 * @param : {Number} hours 
 */
function hoursToSeconds(hours) {
    var seconds = (hours * 60 * 60);
    return seconds;
}

function storeInCache(data, cacheName){ //Store in cache function
    data.cacheLastUpdateDate = ((new Date).getTime());
    localStorage.setItem(cacheName, JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

And this is the client :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   //Callbacks definitions
    var getUserCallbacks = {
        run: function(data){//Success Callbacks
            console.log(data);
        },
        errors: function(data) {//Error Callbacks
            console.log(data);
        },
        serverError : function(data){//Server Error Callback
            console.log('Error From Server, Ask to backend team');
        },
    }

    var userRequest = { //request Object
        dependency : jQuery, //jQuery as dependency to allow to make an ajax inside the namespace
        request: 'getUser', //Request Name
        userId : 1, //Param
        callbacks :getUserCallbacks, //succes an error callbacks
        allowCache: true, //Cache boolean
        domainEvent: 'getUser' //Custom event Name
    }



    FOF.Users.init(userRequest); //Exec request
});
```